# Getting data for solar radiation

Tags: curated-data, geography

There data for it is available in the web like on [pvgis](http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php#) or [NASA](https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/sse/daily.cgi?email=skip%40larc.nasa.gov&step=1&lat=&lon=&sitelev=&ms=1&ds=1&ys=1988&me=12&de=31&ye=2004&p=clr_dif&submit=Submit&plot=clr_dif). The first one deliveres data for a surface with polar and azimut angle. That would be the kind of data I need. Is there a chance to get the data from within Mathematica? Or can the diffuse and direct solar radiation data made available in Mathematica, like e.g. `WeatherData` or by querying the web site and getting the data in return?